# How to fetch extra data to feed a symfony2 collection field type?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using a basic collection field with Symfony2, and everything is working well.

Say I have:

```
->add('product', 'collection', array(...))
```

Now, in my view, I am calling `product.vars.data.owner` where I have a `oneToOne` `product->getOwner()`.

This is generating one extra request per product in the collection.
Since I can't use a querybuilder in a collection field, how can I make sure it doctrine fetches the product owners in order to avoid those many extra requests?

Comment: what is type of your fields in collection?, You can fetch your entity & entity relations by dql and then pass entity to createForm() method

Comment: My collection's subtype only contains one string attribute of the entity. I can fetch data with dql, yes. how would you do that with createform ?

Comment: plz place your formType code & your entity mapping here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example(I don't see your data mapping & form builder), I hope this help you :

1 : Fetch your data by `dql`,

```
$dql = "select c from category c left join c.product p join p.owner o where c.id = ?1";
$category = $this->createQuery($dql)->setParameter(1, $id)->getSingleResult();
```

2 : Suppose you have a category form that could have many products:

```
class Category
{
    // manyToMany
    private $product
}

$form = $this->createForm(new CategoryType(), $category);
```

3 : If your collection type be an embedded ProductType(form type)
then you can use below line in your template:

```
{{ form.product.vars.data.owner }}
```

Comment: yes, sure, hydrate the object before you send it to the form, that's obviously the right solution here ! thanks :) !

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a querybuilder you could force Doctrine to always load the owner on the product whenever the product is loaded by EAGER loading the association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Owner", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $owner;
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading

Comment: thanks, this works but it's then loading the owner every time I work with the product, that's not really what I'm looking for...